# ListItem Versioning Differences

Tags: 2010, splistitem, version-history

Does anyone know how to programmatically determine if any non-system fields have changed between ListItem versions? I realize that I could iterate through the fields between each version and if I see a change occurs (then keep the version otherwise delete it), but this seems very expensive to do.

When you click on version history for a listitem, you get a nice summary of changes between versions. Is this code/SQL accessible to the developer?

Answer (score 3):

If you take closer look at `versions.aspx` (\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS) you will notice that 'nice summary' is created by iterating over item versions (from line 311 to 357).

My guess is if `versions.aspx` uses iteration to retrieve field changes then this is the only option available.

Edited:
To be completely correct: It is not the only option. You can probably execute query directly on content database but here you have nice explanation why you really don't want to do this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665755/how-to-query-on-sharepoint-database

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this will solve your problem completely, but may help a bit.  To see the SQL being executed, you could enable and use the [developer dashboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512745.aspx).